# not able to get claims into access_token generated by ADFS 3.0 using OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, adfs3.0

1. I have an Angular application(ex. https://localhost:44301) that is
   using Web API(ex. https://localhost:44302) to interact with data.
2. I have an Identity Server 4 (ex. https://localhost:44303) for authentication in which we have even
   configured external login with Azure AD.
3. Our Architecture is something like below :

[image]

3. Now I want to add ADFS 3.0 (even ADFS 4.0 i.e. multiple ADFS) as a external login provider
4. So as per my research I have to go for only OAuth 2.0 with
   Authrization Code Grant.

   **ref:**  https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-in-ADFS
5. For that what type of configuration should I add into ADFS server. I am mainly confused about:

   - what should add as relying party trust identifier ?
   - what should as a resource into authorization request ?
   - what configurations for custom claims ?

Comment: You mean you want to add ADFS as an external IDP to idsrv4?

Comment: Correct, I want to in implement the same

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can do this.

You can add ADFS via:

- SAML 2
- WS Fed
- OpenID Connect

So:

- [SAML](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/connecting-adfs-5-0-and-the-sustainsys-saml-v2-0-for-net-core-stack-1c8dd8f4aecd) or you could use the Rock Solid Knowledge stack described in that blog
- WS-Fed - use the built-in ASP.NET Core SP option
- OIDC is doable but rather go with above

In both these cases, ADFS is a CP to idsrv4. idsrv4 is an SP to ADFS.

If you go with OIDC, it's an application group.

Comment: As mentioned above in question I want to support for AdFS 3.0 but OpenIDConnect is not supported for ADFS 3.0 So I am using OAuth 2.0 and my questions are listed as above

Comment: Your question says "even ADFS 4.0". Use SAML or WS-Fed.

Comment: You can't do this with OAuth. ADFS 3.0 is for API only.

Comment: Yes, You are correct man !!! So from SAML 2 and WS Fed for which should I go as per the architecture ?

Comment: They will both work. SAML is harder to get working but it depends on your knowledge of the protocol. SAML has both free and commercial offerings.